# When AVPlayer is playing a video file, the video pauses when switching tabs in the Tab Bar

Tags: ios, avplayer

"When using AVPlayer to play video, why does the video pause when switching tabs in the Tab Bar? I've already configured the application to allow background playback. However, if the application goes to the background and then returns to the foreground, the video will pause when switching tabs. If the application has not been to the background, switching tabs won't interrupt the video playback. Could you help me understand why this is happening and how to prevent the video from pausing when switching tabs?"

STEPS TO REPRODUCE
I used the official code to handle background video playback when the app is sent to the background.

For the AVPlayer video playback page, if the app has not entered the background, the video can play normally and will not pause when switching tabs in the Tab Bar. However, once the app has been sent to the background from the video playback page and then returned to the foreground, the video will pause when switching tabs.

For the AVPlayer video playback page, if the app has not entered the background, the video can play normally and will not pause when switching tabs in the Tab Bar. However, once the app has been sent to the background from the video playback page and then returned to the foreground, the video will pause when switching tabs.